# execCommand creating invalid html

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I'm creating a simple RTE for a application, it doesn't need to be too involved so I thought that using execCommands could be the best solution. I've run into trouble, however, with the commands creating invalid HTML. Here is the javascript I'm using, any insight into what is causing this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $('.turnEditOn').live('click',function(){
        richTextEditor.document.designMode = 'ON';
        $('#richTextEditor').focus();   });
    $('#bold').live('click',function(){
        richTextEditor.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
        $('#richTextEditor').focus();   });
    $('#underline').live('click',function(){
        richTextEditor.document.execCommand('underline',false,null);
        $('#richTextEditor').focus();   });
    $('#italic').live('click',function(){
        richTextEditor.document.execCommand('italic',false,null);
        $('#richTextEditor').focus();   });
```

Comment: What is `richTextEditor` variable. Is a pointer to an iframe window object? What is `$('#richTextEdito')` and `$('#richTextEditor')`? Is same objects (typo)? jQuery object `$('#richTextEditor')` points to the same object as `richTextEditor` variable?

Comment: Yes that should've been $('#richTextEditor') they are the same object. Its a iframe with id richTextEditor.

Comment: What's wrong with the HTML it produces?

Comment: <span underline;\\\"="\"\"" underline;\"="" style="\"text-decoration:">testing</span>. I just thought of this, but could setting the src attribute of the iframe be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="turnEditOn" class="command">on</div>
<div id="bold" class="command"><b>B</b></div>
<div id="italic" class="command"><i>I</i></div>
<div id="underline" class="command"><u>U</u></div>
<div class="command" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('richTextEditor').contentDocument.body.innerHTML);">Show HTML</div>
<br/>
<iframe id="richTextEditor" style="width:500px;height:300px;"></iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT+jQuery(onDomReady):

```
var richTextEditor=document.getElementById("richTextEditor");
$('#turnEditOn').live('click',function(){
    richTextEditor.contentDocument.designMode = 'ON';
    richTextEditor.contentDocument.body.contentEditable=true;
    // Switch FireFox RTE execCommand engine to work in same manner as IE
    try{richTextEditor.contentDocument.execCommand('styleWithCSS',false,false);}
    catch(e){}
    richTextEditor.focus();
});
$('#bold').live('click',function(){
    richTextEditor.contentDocument.execCommand('bold',false,null);
    richTextEditor.focus();
});
$('#underline').live('click',function(){
    richTextEditor.contentDocument.execCommand('underline',false,null);
    richTextEditor.focus();
});
$('#italic').live('click',function(){
    richTextEditor.contentDocument.execCommand('italic',false,null);
    richTextEditor.focus();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d2L2A/

Read about [Rich Text Editing in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)